# setting default options for cryptsetup

Tags: configuration, defaults, cryptsetup

Is there a way to set default options for cryptsetup? For example, lets say I want to make sure that I only open cryptsetup devices with the `-r` option. I would like to add it to a config file, so that I don't have to type it every time (and potentially forget it)

Reading `man cryptsetup` did not reveal any information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is no configuration file for `cryptsetup`. You can of course define an alias and put that somewhere where it gets read in at login:

```
alias cryptsetup='cryptsetup --readonly'
```

Comment: Not a huge fan of using aliases.